# Month and week day language on a real device

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am creating an app that will be used mostly by spanish users.

I don't have access to a real device to test the app, but I have changed the iOS simulator language to spanish and the region to Spain.

In the app I am using NSDateFormatter to convert NSDate to strings, but on the simulator the strings for week day and month are in english.

This is the result :

[image]

My question is: should I change the strings to spanish programmatically or will they be shown in spanish on a real device?

Thank you.

UPDATED

Here the code I have so far:

```
 //convertir fecha
    NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"LOCALE = %@",language);

//NSLog result = es

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:fecha];

    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSDateFormatter *weekDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [weekDay setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    [weekDay setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

UPDATE 2

I have changed the simulator configuration to spanish/Spain, as you may see in the picture, but dates appear in english !!! WHhy?

[image]

Comment: Explicitly create a locale with the desired language set, and use that to set the date formatter locale.  You can ifdef it if you wish, so it will be removed in the shipped product.

Comment: @HotLicks, please take a look at my updated question. I have checked that the current locale is 'es' (spanish), but the labels are still in english.

Comment: Rather than using `currentLocale`, create your own locale.  Unfortunately, I can't find a full example of this, and don't have a Mac right now to try it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in the simulator that you have set the region to Spanish/Spain (as opposed to Spain, which can be English in Spain). (The language setting is irrelevant to dates.) On the Settings/General/International screen it will show you a sample of the current Region Format; that must be in Spanish for your code to work.

[image: International Settings page]

To see in your app, add the following code:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
NSLog(@"LOCALE = %@/%@",language,   [calendar.locale localeIdentifier ] );
```

The calendar Locale can be en_ES, which means English in Spain or es_ES, which means Spanish in Spain.

All of which means that your code is fine; on a real device in Spain, you'll have no problem, and to see this, you just need to set your simulator's settings like a device in Spain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanation. I have updated my question to include a screenshot from my simulator configuration. I have set language = spanish, region format=Spain, like you, but on your simulator the date format is spanish, and on my simulator it is still in english, why is it not in spanish, like yours?

Comment: You need to go into the region, and select Spanish>Spain, NOT Spain.  (Try this in English language.) Until the preference screen shows Spanish in your date at the bottom, you have the wrong setting.

Comment: Great!  Now you can get back to actually coding!